# Ajax BeginForm not calling action in controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been trying to implement a system where a user can add/delete child entities of the current entity, however I have been having trouble using the `Ajax.BeginForm` helper method (this is my first real use of it). Basically when I click the submit button, it won't call the specified action in my controller.

I have searched for several hours now without success, most of the issues people have had before is due to certain libraries not being referenced, but I'm pretty sure that's not the issue here.

Anyway, here are the important parts of my code:

**Partial View**

```
@using MyProject.Domain.Entities;
@model MyProject.WebUI.ViewModels.UserCustomerViewModel

<div id = "meh222">        
    @using (  
        Ajax.BeginForm("AddCustomer", "User",
            new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "meh222", HttpMethod = "Post" })
            )
    {        
    <label>Customers</label>  

    @*@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Customer", "AddCustomer", "User", new { userID = Model.UserID, customerID = 1001 }, 
        new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "meh222", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @class = "standardbutton" })*@  
    <fieldset>
        <legend>CustomersLegend</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserID)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customers, new SelectList(Model.AllCustomers, "CustomerID", "Name"))
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Customer" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>                 
    }         
    <table class="tbl2" id="tbl2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>CustomerID</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (Customer item in Model.Customers)
            { 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(i => item.CustomerID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(i => item.Name)
                </td>  
                <td>
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCustomer", "User", new { userID = Model.UserID, customerID = item.CustomerID },
                          new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "meh222" }, new { @class = "standardbutton" })    
                </td>       
            </tr>
            }
        }       
        </tbody>     
    </table>
</div>
```

**Main View**

```
<div>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("CustomerPartial", Model.CustomerVM); } 
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public PartialViewResult AddCustomer(UserCustomerViewModel vm)
{
    return PartialView("CustomerPartial");
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class UserCustomerViewModel
{
    public int UserID;
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Customer> AllCustomers { get; set; }
}
```

**Scripts in my _Layout**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Just a couple of notes:

- If you look in my partial view, you can see an `Ajax.ActionLink` commented out. This was what I used before (and it worked), however I needed to hardcode the CustomerID, hence the change to `Ajax.BeginForm` so I can access the value of the DropDownList that is populated from the ViewModel's AllCustomers property.
- The real controller action obviously has more processing, but that isn't the problem here as if I put a breakpoint in the action it isn't even hit.
- I have added the list of scripts just so people know exactly what I am referencing in case that is the issue.

Does anyone have any ideas why my submit isn't accessing the `AddCustomer` action in my controller?

If I haven't decribed the issue properly or you need more information, please let me know and I will try and give more information.

Thanks very much.

**----UPDATE----**

**Error data I got from Chrome's console**

This is under the '500 Internal Server Error' in the console.

```
d.support.ajax.d.ajaxTransport.send    jquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
d.extend.ajax                          jquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
e                                      jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:5
(anonymous function)                   jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:5
E                                      jquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
d.event.handle                         jquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
d.event.add.k.handle.m                 jquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
```

Comment: FYI, for the `scripts`, anything with the same name but `.min` at the end is a duplicate except that it has been minified (removed spaces, etc.) so you only need one of each file, you have duplicates of several. If you don't know the diff, just keep the `.min`'s and remove the others.

Comment: Thanks for that, I never knew. As you can probably guess I'm still learning!

Comment: what happen when you click  the button? did it do a postback? have you checked the browser console if there was an error?

Comment: No problem, unfortunately I don't see a problem in your code. Try removing the duplicates and see if it helps.

Comment: You may want to look into a tool called Fiddler.  It allows you to see what is happening between the browser and the server.  It will show you if a call is actually being made and if so what url it's going to.

Comment: @codingbiz I have just checked it now and I am getting a '500 Internal Server Error' which I assume there is an issue with the data I am trying to send to the server. I have added the details of the error in my original post. If anyone can offer any more hints it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please remove the `MicrosoftAjax.js` and `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js` they are not needed in MVC3. And also for each script use the full version `jquery-1.5.1.js` or the minimized one `jquery-1.5.1.min.js` but not both. So fix your script usings because it can be that this is causing your problems.

Comment: @nemesv I've just removed all those scripts and unfortunatly I get the same error.